# Why is Firestore rounding 64 bit integers?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, integer

I'm trying to store 64 bit integers from a python program in my Firestore database. The problem is that it seems like the last digits are rounded off.

```py
doc = db.collection('questions').document('0MPvbeTEglD9lbpDq6xm')
ints = [9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775533, 9223372036854775267]
doc.update({
    'random': ints
})
```

When I look in the database they are stored as:

`random = [9223372036854776000, 9223372036854776000, 9223372036854775000}`

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) 64 bit signed integers are supported. What could the problem be?

Comment: Are the digits rounded, or just truncated?

Comment: How do I figure that out?

Comment: Truncated means that digits are "cut-off". For example, if you have 0.1234567 and the number gets truncated after the 4th digit then it becomes 0.1234 without necessarily rounding the number, whereas rounding by itself means it becomes 0.123457 for example, or simply 0 if you round to nearest integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not 100% certain, but my guess is that what you're seeing is due to the fact that JavaScript integers are not 64 bits in size.  They're actually more like [53 bits](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5).  Since the Firebase console is a web app implemented with JavaScript, it probably can't understand the full 64 bits of very large integers you write to it.

What I'd recommend is reading the values back out of your document with another python program instead of checking the values in the console.  If they're the same as what you wrote, then there's not real problem here.  You just can't trust the rendering of the values in the console.

Comment: That's it, they came back represented correctly when I fetched them with a Python program.

Comment: It's not purely readibility unfortunately. We have a cloud function that appends new firestore data to a google spreadsheet with an onWrite trigger, and the long values in the documents are written in the 53bit representation.

Comment: It seems like an unacceptable oversimplification in the Javascript Firestore API... It could introduce a custom Integer type, like it does for Timestamp, possibly having a configurable option for enabling it, whatever. Database API loosing data is not acceptable.

Comment: @cubuspl42 You can always file a feature request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support