# Firebase realtime database int64 precision lost?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, precision, int64

I have noticed int64 type precision lost, in my project Firebase realtime database:

- When I add a new child or edit the child value in browser;
- When I add a new child or edit the child value via my (C++) code: as SetValue(int64_t)   or even as SetValue(firebase::Variant::kTypeInt64);

The precision lost starts after 53 bits:

```
//   9007199254740991 <-  I set 53 bits value.."11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
//   9007199254740991  -> it records correctly;
//  18014398509481983 <-  I set 54 bits value."111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
//  18014398509481984  -> it records as......"1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
// seems it declared as int64_t but saved as float?
```

1. Can someone reproduce it?
2. Is it bug or feature?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you work with data in the Firebase console, it's going to be subject to the limits of JavaScript.  JS always stores [numbers](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5) of 64 bit **floating point** numbers (not integers).  So, if you're dealing with 64 bit integers, some of that precision gets lost if you're using JS.

Try ignoring what you see in the console, and only perform reads and writes with code that handles 64 bit integers correctly.  If that doesn't work, then there is something inside Realtime Database that imposes a similar limitation.  The documentation doesn't make any claims about the precision of numbers, as far as I can see.  However, Firestore (the successor to Realtime Database) does [make a claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) that 64bit integers are OK.  So if this is important to you, you might want to switch (though [it still does have problems with those numbers in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414755/why-is-firestore-rounding-64-bit-integers), due to JS limits).