# storing as integer vs string size

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have checked the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/storage-size) but I got confused a bit. When storing a long integer such as `265628143862153200`. Would it be more efficient to store it as a string of integer.

This is what I need help with is the below calculation corrent?

**Integer:**

length of `265628143862153200` *8 ?

**String:**

length of `265628143862153200` +1 ?

Comment: Why do you want to ever store a number as a string?  If you do that, you lose the ability to treat it like a number for things like range queries and ordering.  Losing that ability doesn't seem to be worth saving a few bytes.

Comment: One main reasons other then size, When storing `303069538315010058` as a number it is `303069538315010050` as you can see the last digit is lost. This is only in the GUI, so if an non-tech admin review the data manually it will not be the same.

Comment: Also when appending a integer using the GUI (website) is turns all previous elements into floats. which makes them lose some digits +- 10 for what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase console is not meant to be part of administrative workflows.  It's just for discovery and development.  If you have production-grade procedures to follow, you should only write code for that using the provided SDKs.  Typically, developers make their own admin sites to deal with data in Firesotre.

Also, you should know that JavaScript integers are [not "big" enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414755/why-is-firestore-rounding-64-bit-integers) to store data to the full size provided by Firestore.  If you want to use the full size of a number field, you will have to use a system that supports Firestore's full 64 bit signed integer type.

If you must store numbers bigger than either limit, and be able to modify them by hand, consider instead storing multiple numbers, similar to the way Firestore's timestamp stores seconds and nanoseconds as separate numbers, so that the full value can overflow greater than signed 64 bits.