# Why is Firestore rounding numbers of 16+ digits?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to store a 20 digits number from a Vue app in my Firestore database. The problem is that it seems like the 3 last digits are rounded off, and if the number starts with a `0`, the zero get cut off of the number.
It appears that the problem starts with numbers with more than 16 digits, if I save `12345678910111213141` when I look in the database it is stored as: `12345678910111214000`
There was a similar problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414755/why-is-firestore-rounding-64-bit-integers), but when the number was retrieved in the program, it got the right number instead of the rounded number shown in Firestore... In my case, I'm getting the rounded value in my app too.
How do I fix this?

Comment: If it's a unique identifier  `number` is the wrong type for it. The safest type for a unique identifiers is `string`. If it's indeed a number (you're doing mathematical operations with it) then you might want to have a look at [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). Note you can't mix numbers and bigInts in the same operation and (obviously) you might lose data when coercing from bigInt to number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the other question, your number is exceeding the size of a JavaScript number, which is a signed 53 bit number.  Firestore is capable of storing up to 64 bits, and if you try to read the number back in JavaScript or view in the console, you will lose data.  (The issue is not the number of digits, it's the magnitude of the number with respect to the max number of bits available to store it internally.)

Numbers that start with 0 always lose leading zeroes when written to any pure number store.  Leading zeroes are meaningless for the purpose of computation, so they are dropped from the representation.  If you want to display leading zeroes for whatever reason, you should format the number as a string and pad the zeroes before printing it.

If you want to store a formatted number without losing any of its formatting, or if you want to store something bigger than 64 bits, you should store it as a string type field instead of a number.  But then you will lose the ability to perform rational mathematical comparisons on it in your queries.

Comment: Summary: No, I can't fix it XD... Thanks for the explanation, changing the field type isn't a big deal in my use case, but it's a shame that I can't keep my data model as clean as I want.