# How to use 64 bit integers for Firestore in browsers?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, bigint

Firestore can store [64 bit signed integers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). However Javascript's `number` type has a 53 bit mantissa. How to read/write big numbers with Firestore without losing precision?

I tried:

1. Using `BigInt`: The Javascript SDK doesn't support it.
2. Using strings: This could do but I need sort operations for numbers.

For some reason the [admin SDK has BigInt support](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/pull/1016), but the client library not.

Comment: I think [Why is Firestore rounding 64 bit intergers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414755/why-is-firestore-rounding-64-bit-integers) explains it best.

Answer (score 3):

Convert BigInt to a string and write it as a string to firestore. This modifies all clients you use to convert from string to BigInt and vice versa but will allow you to store large numbers as needed in the browser at least (due to JavaScript being 53 bit precision-ish). Not ideal but it works. If you need to query on that field in Firestore, I would then use a Cloud function to store the number in another field for querying. I realize this is not the ideal solution, but may help solve your issue in a pinch.

Finally, I would recommend doing is logging a feature request to the FireStore SDK for web to support BigInt.